# Failure to pass information from one activity to another Activity Android studio

Tags: android

I want to use Intent to pass 2 information (msgTotalCost & msgProfit) from the first activity to the second activity, but not sure what make the program crashed (Unfortunately the application has been stopped).

Here is the method's code in the first activity(would be activated when button is pressed):

```
public void sendInput(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    EditText editTextPurPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_PP);
    EditText editTextSelPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_SP);
    EditText editTextStkQty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_QTY);
    EditText editTextLotSize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_LS);

    Double msgPurPrice = Double.parseDouble(editTextPurPrice.getText().toString());
    Double msgSelPrice = Double.parseDouble(editTextSelPrice.getText().toString());
    int msgStkQty = Integer.parseInt(editTextStkQty.getText().toString());
    int msgLotSize = Integer.parseInt(editTextLotSize.getText().toString());

    Double totalCost = getTotalCost(msgPurPrice, msgSelPrice, msgStkQty, msgLotSize);
    Double profit = getProfit(msgPurPrice, msgSelPrice, msgStkQty, totalCost);

    String msgTotalCost = String.valueOf(totalCost);
    String msgProfit = String.valueOf(profit);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TOTALCOST, msgTotalCost);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PROFIT, msgProfit);

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Extras key values is placed under the first activity class

```
public final static String EXTRA_TOTALCOST = "com.xxxxx.calculator.InfoActivity.totalcost";
public final static String EXTRA_PROFIT = "com.xxxxx.calculator.InfoActivity.profit";
```

Here is the code of second activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String totalCost = intent.getStringExtra(InfoActivity.EXTRA_TOTALCOST);
    String profit = intent.getStringExtra(InfoActivity.EXTRA_PROFIT);
    TextView costOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTTCost);
    TextView profitOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultProfit);
    costOutput.setText(totalCost);
    profitOutput.setText(profit);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
}
```

local as below

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxxx.calculator/com.xxxxx.calculator.ResultActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: yet another premature `findViewById` call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with intent and data transfer. You just need to do `setContentView` of the layout **before** you can find its view elements with `findViewById`.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String totalCost = intent.getStringExtra(InfoActivity.EXTRA_TOTALCOST);
    String profit = intent.getStringExtra(InfoActivity.EXTRA_PROFIT);
    TextView costOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTTCost);
    TextView profitOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultProfit);
    costOutput.setText(totalCost);
    profitOutput.setText(profit);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
}
```

to

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String totalCost = intent.getStringExtra(InfoActivity.EXTRA_TOTALCOST);
    String profit = intent.getStringExtra(InfoActivity.EXTRA_PROFIT);
    TextView costOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTTCost);
    TextView profitOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultProfit);
    costOutput.setText(totalCost);
    profitOutput.setText(profit);
}
```